# How to sorting parent elements only by their root nodes in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I got a XML file looks like

```
<root>
<number>1</number>
<number>
    <deleted>0</deleted>
    3
</number>
<number>2</number>
</root>
```

I want to sort the file only by valid value, like the valid value of the second  element is 3. I only need the value not contained in any child elements.
So the desired output looks like:

```
<root>
<number>1</number>
<number>2</number>
<number>
 <deleted>0</deleted>
 3
</number>
</root>
```

I tried to use `except` in sorting but it didn't work. My stylesheet:

```
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="number">
                <xsl:sort select=". except del"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Thank you!

**Add:**
I changed the XML into

```
<root>
    <number>1</number>
    <number>
        1
        <deleted>0</deleted>
        3
    </number>
    <number>2</number>
</root>
```

Insert a node before the `<deleted>` tag, then the `<xsl:sort select="text()">` can't work. An error message says 
`XTTE1020: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the @select attribute of xsl:sort (text("1"), text("3"))`
Please help :(

Answer (score 1):

`.` matches the current node, which is `number`, so doing `. except deleted` is not really going to achieve much. You need to sort on the child node that is not `deleted`

```
 <xsl:sort select="node() except deleted" data-type="number" />
```

Although, it is really only the text node you want, so you don't really need `except` at all

```
<xsl:sort select="text()" data-type="number" />
```

However, this will only work if you strip out white-space nodes first with `xsl:strip-space` (otherwise you will get an error about the sort selecting a sequence of nodes). Alternatively you could do `<xsl:sort select="text()[normalize-space()]" data-type="number" />`

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="number">
        <xsl:sort select="text()" data-type="number" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, the above stylesheet will work in XSLT 1.0, but if you are using XSLT 2.0, then you can simplify this a bit with `xsl:perform-sort` instead...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:perform-sort select="number">
        <xsl:sort select="text()" data-type="number" />
      </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: And, if you have multiple child text nodes, then do this to concatenate them...

```
<xsl:sort select="string-join(text()/normalize-space())" data-type="number" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Also thank you for explaining about the ```except```.

Comment: I found it is problematic when their is nodes before the ```<deleted>```, like```<number>
1
 <deleted>0</deleted>
 3
</number>```
It should sort by the value of ```13```, but it shows error. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Change the sort to `<xsl:sort select="string-join(text()/normalize-space())" data-type="number" />`